# como poner datos diferentes mediante un while

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He hecho un codigo para que me traiga una base de datos y he usado un ciclo while el problema es que quiero hacer una tabla de dos columnas y nose como hacer que el while me genere la tabla con dos etiquetas td alguien tiene una idea de como puedo hacer, aqui les dejo el codigo

`   $TotalReg = $conetar->query("SELECT * FROM tutoriales");

```
//Se divide la cantidad de registro de la BD con la cantidad a mostrar 
$TotalRegistro = ceil($TotalReg->num_rows/$CantidadMostrar);
//Consulta SQL
$consultavistas ="SELECT
                    tutoriales.URL_imagen,
                    tutoriales.Nombre,
                    tutoriales.Href,
                    tutoriales.Categoria
                    FROM
                    tutoriales
                    ORDER BY
                    tutoriales.ID ASC
                    LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantidadMostrar)." , ".$CantidadMostrar;
                   // echo $consultavistas;
$consulta=$conetar->query($consultavistas);
?>
<div class="main">
    <?php
     echo "<center><table class=\"main\">";
while ($lista=$consulta->fetch_row()) {
     echo '<tr><td><img src="'. $lista[0] . '" class=\'timg\'></td></tr>
            <tr><td class=\'title-table\'>'. $lista[1] . '</td></tr>
            <tr><td class=\'category\'><span class=\'text\'>' .$lista[3] . '</span></td></tr>';

}
    echo "</table></center>";
    ?>

 </div>`
```

necesito que en el while me ponga otro td en el tr pero con diferentes datos de la misma query, espero explicarme

la consulta hace lo que se ve en la imagen yo lo que necesito es que haga lo mismo pero a la par y que no sean los mismos 3 de ahi, espero se mas entendible ahora

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que poner las dos etiquetas antes del `while`, algo así más o menos:

```
 echo "<center><table class=\"main\">";
 echo "<tr><td>Columna1</td><td>Columna2</td></tr>";

 while ($lista=$consulta->fetch_row()) {
        //... resto del código
```

#### PD

Me parece extraño que crees varias filas (`tr`)  dentro del `while`, generalmente ahí se crea una sola fila y dentro de ella todas las celdas.

Comment: ya la reedite para que vea mi intencion y pues gracias igual

Comment: @LeninRosales no logro entender qué es lo que quieres realmente. Si quieres más `td` con más datos, los agregas del mismo modo que los otros usando el índice de `$lista` donde esté el dato, por ejemplo `$lista[4]`, o `$lista[5]`, etc. Dentro del `while` tú estás creando una sola columna.

Comment: el problema radica en que $lista[5] y 4 no existen solo existe del 1 al 4 entonces si agrego otro td solo puedo usar del 1 al 4 y como ya esta puesto en uno, el dato del otro td es el mismo que ya esta puesta y eso es lo que quiero cambiar, que en el otro td sean datos diferentes puedes ver la imagen para tener una idea, ya tengo una columna pero no puedo hacer otra con diferentes datos sino que el while me los duplica

Comment: @LeninRosales entonces el problema es la forma en que tienes organizado tu array `$lista`. ¿Por qué no lo ordenas de forma que te quede todo en una sola fila? Lo que quieres hacer se podría con dos `while` y concatenando todo en una variable, pero es más complicado y poco performante, porque estarías leyendo el array dos veces. Lo correcto en estos casos es **organizar bien tu array**, o bien la consulta, de modo que los datos necesarios vengan en una sola fila. Por lo que dices, parece que los datos vienen en diferentes filas ¿?